# Adicionar um repositório remoto sem dar merge

Tags: git, github, git-remote

Galera preciso de uma super ajuda!

Eu desenvolvo games no curso que faço e utilizo a unity3d como Engine.

Possuo um projeto que pode ser versionado pelo unitycollab, mas isso é utilizado para a produção dentro do ambiente de desenvolvimento da Unity. Para versionar o projeto, utilizo o GitHub.

Tenho um problema que toda vez que preciso instalar o projeto na máquina para continuar o desenvolvimento, preciso adicionar o `origin remote` para o repositório que está hospedado no git. Mas toda vez que faço essa adição, não consigo sincronizar com o repositório remoto.

Primeiramente faço: `git init` para inicializar o projeto que baixei do collab, da unity.

Depois, adiciono o endereço remoto utilizando `remote add origin {link do repositório}`

Agora, preciso sincronizar o projeto baixado (collab) com o projeto remoto (GitHub), dou um `git pull`

[image: Saida ao rodar git pull]

O git-scm solicita que eu faça um `git pull origin master` (A branch padrão atualmente é a build-2). Porém, quando rodo o comando tenho esta saída.

```
From https://github.com/juniobiel/flora-game
 * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        Assets/Arquivos.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Animations.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Animations/TitleMenu.anim
        Assets/Arquivos/Animations/TitleMenu.anim.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Animations/TitleMenu.controller
        Assets/Arquivos/Animations/TitleMenu.controller.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/JandaManateeBubble.ttf
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/JandaManateeBubble.ttf.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/JandaManateeSolid.ttf
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/JandaManateeSolid.ttf.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/LICENSE.txt
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/LICENSE.txt.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/Lemon Juice.otf
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/Lemon Juice.otf.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/National Cartoon.ttf
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/National Cartoon.ttf.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/Pine Forest Personal Use Only.otf
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/Pine Forest Personal Use Only.otf.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/Rationale-Regular.ttf
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/Rationale-Regular.ttf.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/Schoolbell-Regular.ttf
        Assets/Arquivos/Fonts/Schoolbell-Regular.ttf.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Maya.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Maya/TreeHouse.mb
        Assets/Arquivos/Maya/TreeHouse.mb.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Photoshop.meta
        Assets/Arquivos/Photoshop/Menu.psd
        Assets/Arquivos/Photoshop/Menu.psd.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Materials.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Materials/atlass_1_1.mat
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Materials/atlass_1_1.mat.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Materials/atlass_1_2.mat
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Materials/atlass_1_2.mat.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment1.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment1/bush_segment_1.fbx
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment1/bush_segment_1.fbx.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment1/bush_segment_1.prefab
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment1/bush_segment_1.prefab.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment3.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment3/bush_segment_3.fbx
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment3/bush_segment_3.fbx.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment3/bush_segment_3.prefab
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/BushSegment3/bush_segment_3.prefab.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/Bush_Segment2.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/Bush_Segment2/bush_segment_2.fbx
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/Bush_Segment2/bush_segment_2.fbx.meta
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSegment/Bush_Segment2/bush_segment_2.prefab
        Assets/Assets Importados/AlignedGames/Polygonal Foliage Asset Package/Art/Models/BushSeg
Aborting
```

Já pesquisei algumas soluções e não encontrei nenhuma que pudesse me ajudar a desconsiderar esse merge.

Eu não preciso que o GitHub faça o merge, pois o Collab já é responsável por sincronizar a pasta com a versão atual do projeto. Apenas preciso que o GitHub me permita reupar as novas alterações do projeto, como os updates de código e tudo mais...

Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de alguns dias mexendo um pouco com os repositórios cheguei a seguinte solução:

Primeiro, devo lembrar que a versão que está no git é diferente da nova máquina que estou tentando baixar o projeto, então devo fazer o clone do repositório.

Para evitar conflitos dentro da Unity, excluo por inteiro a pasta Library (onde contém as informações de pacotes e etc.), é preciso fazer isso por conta do collab, ele irá sincronizar com uma lista antiga e pode dar erro na utilização do próprio collab.

Dentro do UnityHub, adiciono o projeto recém clonado e abro com o editor que preciso.

Feito isso, a Unity vai fazer o rebuild da pasta Library e o collab vai solicitar o Update do projeto.

Depois de atualizar, é só fechar a Unity e fazer o commit normalmente no Git para atualizar e mantê-lo sincronizado com o repositório na nova máquina.

Espero que possa ajudar caso alguém enfrente o mesmo problema...